# why my hardware info is exepressed differently?

Tags: 20.04, hardware

I recently switched from windows 10 into ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS and I checked my hardware info from settings and it was given in different way, as my laptop's ram is 8196mb it was given 7.2gb, also the graphics was shown differently from windows. As I am new on ubuntu I want to know if that difference between windows and ubuntu is normal or I should go back to the one how installed me ubuntu.

Comment: It is normal...

Answer (score 2):

Different programs report different aspects of your hardware and present them differently. This is true regardless of operating systems. One program may report the amount of physical RAM installed, another the amount of RAM remaining after on-board graphics has grabbed part of it for its frame buffer, a third the actual available RAM after the OS kernel is loaded. For graphics adapters, one program may report the controller family, another the vendor name, and so on.

So, on the generality level of your question, the only answer is: it's probably normal. For specific reported values that tickle your curiosity or suspicion, you can try to sort out exactly where the difference is coming from, but in the majority of cases it is not worth the effort.